# Remote monitoring of system stats with node.js

Tags: linux, node.js, monitoring

We have implemented a monitoring solution in node.js, which does some basic checks for database integrity and API up-time. We want to expand this system to collect basic system stats of our Linux servers like CPU and disc usage. Some of these servers are behind a firewall which is out of our control, with only some very basic ports open (ssh,ftp,http,https).

How can I gather the system information of these servers in node.js. Are there monitoring systems which expose these information through a (secured) RESTful API?

Comment: I have no idea about a restful API, I would just make a system call through node.js using ssh (assuming you're running on linux) using key/host-based authentication and perform various commands and parse the stdout/stderr output - and exposing the result through node.js.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Nagios sounds good, didn't know that before. Thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: So your question is basically "how do I remotely monitor system stats?"

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer if there is already a solution tailored for node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of success with this ssh client written in javascript:
https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

Answer (score 0):

So there tons of available solutions for monitoring system stats: Nagios, Zabbix, Scout, Cacti. There are even some hosted ones like ServerDensity.

All of these systems should cover the top-level stats: CPU, RAM, Disk IO & Network. They all have a plug-in infrastructure so that you can send custom stats (API uptime, DB availability) and send them along with the regular stats.

If you're running on a cloud infrastructure somewhere, many of these provide information "out of the box", generally in your account dashboard (see guys like Joyent or Azure).

Big question here is *"what else do you need"*?

Answer (score 0):

Use NRPE from Nagios as a client on the box you want to monitor. It's fairly simple to set up and it's API is documentented. http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details